# Twitter Bootsrap Carousel .carousel(number) not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the `.carousel(number)` method on Twitter Bootstrap Carousel plugin. Somehow I can't get it working. The carousel itself is up and running, so does the `.carousel('next')` method.

```
$('#carousel-nav a').click(function(q){
 q.preventDefault();
 targetSlide = $(this).attr('data-to');
 //this one doesn't work $('#my-carousel').carousel(targetSlide); 
 $('#my-carousel').carousel('next');
});
```

Here is the markup

```
<ul id="carousel-nav" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#my-carousel" data-to="0" >Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#my-carousel" data-to="1" >Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#my-carousel" data-to="2" >Slide 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any clue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are 0 based like an array. Try this:

```
    var targetSlide = $(this).attr('data-to') -1;
```

I just subtracted 1 from your targetSlide variable. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you have to parse to int

```
targetSlide = parseInt($(this).attr('data-to'));
```

Answer (score 0):

changed the marked up to :

```
<ul id="carousel-nav" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#my-carousel" data-to="1" >Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#my-carousel" data-to="2" >Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#my-carousel" data-to="3" >Slide 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the script to ( thanks to @user1209713 ):

```
$('#carousel-nav a').click(function(q){
    q.preventDefault();
    targetSlide = $(this).attr('data-to')-1;
    $('#my-carousel').carousel(targetSlide);
});
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

parseInt worked for me thanks @stalin, also if ever you want to run actions, do them individually on the callback for better result.

```
$('#carousel-nav a').click(function(){
 var targetSlide = parseInt($(this).attr('data-cigar'));
 $('#someElement').fadeOut('fast',function(){
   $('#otherElement').fadeIn('fast', function(){
     $('#my-carousel').carousel(targetSlide);
   });
 });
});
```