# How to jump to a specific item in Bootstrap's Carousel?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Using Bootstrap's Carousel, I want to be able to click on a link and jump to a specific slide in the carousel. How do I do that? What jquery do I have to add?

Here's my html (it doesn't work but gives you a sense of what I want to do):

```
<a href="#panel">Panel</a>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div id="panel" class="item">
...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got it to work.

Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256314/twitter-bootsrap-carousel-carouselnumber-not-working

Answer (score 26):

if your links are in the same order of the panels you can do something like:

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    $('#carousel').carousel($(this).index());
});
```

if you just have a single link just hardcode it:

```
var i = 2; //index of the panel    
$('#link').on('click', function() {
    $('#carousel').carousel(i);
});
```

from the docs:

```
Methods:

carousel(options)

Initializes the carousel with an optional options object and starts cycling through items.

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
.carousel('cycle')

Cycles through the carousel items from left to right.

.carousel('pause')

Stops the carousel from cycling through items.

.carousel(number)

Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array).

.carousel('prev')

Cycles to the previous item.

.carousel('next')

Cycles to the next item.
```

Comment: I tried both methods. I added your jquery to the bootstrap.js file and changing "link" to "panel" but it doesn't work.

I also tried putting the <a href="#panel">Panel</a> inside <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

for me the specified scripted method did not work, however based on another example I was able to make it work using data tags

```
<a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" href="#">First</a>
```

Please note that `data-slide-to` index is based on 0, and this was tested on Bootstrap 4

Comment: Excellent, no need for JavaScript, exactly what I was looking for.