# Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x data slider calling .carousel(number) not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I have a data slider for bootstrap based on http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/ and a bootstrap carousel. When the dragging starts I'd like the carousel to go to a specific slide. For this I've adapted this .carousel(number) fix [Twitter Bootsrap Carousel .carousel(number) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256314/twitter-bootsrap-carousel-carouselnumber-not-working) but it's not working :(

the slider:

```
<div class="well">
<form id="carousel-nav">
<input type="text" href="#my-carousel" data-to="2" class="slider"  data-slider-   selection="after">
</form>
</div>
```

the javascript:

```
 <script>
$(function() {

$('.slider').slider();

});</script>


<script>
$('#carousel-nav input').click(function(q){
q.preventDefault();
targetSlide = $(this).attr('data-to')-1;
$('#my-carousel').carousel(targetSlide);
});
</script>
```

any ideas? thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you post the carousel code too? What's not working? Does nothing happen, or does the carousel move to the wrong slide?

Answer (score 0):

**html**:

```
<div class="container">

<input id="dp5" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="3" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="1" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="none" data-slider-tooltip="show">


    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
$('#dp5').slider()
.on('slideStop', function(ev){
 $('#myCarousel').carousel($('#dp5').val()-1);
});

/* also set the slider when the carousel moves */

 $('#myCarousel')
.on('slid', function(e){
$('#dp5').slider('setValue', $(".active", e.target).index()+1);
});
```