# data-slide to ID - Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a thumbnail carousel using bootstrap carousel. However I need to modify the data-slide behaviour as I'm pulling in the carousel items dynamically.
So what I'm trying to do is add an ID (something like 3672764 which will be the image ID) to the data-slide-to attribute and on clicking on the thumbnail it should slide to the slide that has the same ID.

This is the code:

```
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active srle" data-id="{{ image.id }}">
      <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1000x1000' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" data-product-featured-image>
      <p>{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}</p>
      </div>
      {% for image in product.images offset:1 %}
      <div class="item" data-id="{{ image.id }}">
      <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1000x1000' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
      <p>{{ image.alt | escape }}</p>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>



        <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide thumbnails-carousel vertical" data-ride="false">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
      {% for image in product.images %}
      <div class="grid__item carousel-padding">
        <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="{{ image.id }}" class="thumb"><img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '160x160' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-product-single-thumbnail>
  </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
 </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Bootstrap already has this feature check: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256314/twitter-bootsrap-carousel-carouselnumber-not-working